# iOS string uploading AFNetworking 2 - Xcode 5

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, uploading

I am sending a string to my server with AFNetworking and it works well. This is my code:

```
- (void)startWithContentString:(NSString *)contentString {
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"string": @"Anne"};
[manager POST:@"http://xxxxx.php" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
}
```

If I replace @"Anne" by a more complicate string like @"--diner--1245366-tomorrow-2014-03-04--", it still works well.

What I want to do and have difficulties doing : Instead of putting the content of my string (@"xxxx"), I want it to be a variable string that I calculate myself depending on users answers, like :

```
NSString *myString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",str11,str0a,str11,str0b,str11,str0bb,str11,str0c,str11,str0cc,str11,str1,str11,str2,str11,str3,str11,str4,str11,str5,str11,str6,str11,str7,str11,str8,str11];
```

but if i replace @"Anne" by myString, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: did you check, if mystring isn't nil?

Comment: and what does *it doesn't work anymore.* mean in this case?

Comment: @vikinggosegundo No the string isn't equal to nil and by not working I mean it doesn't upload anything. The dictionary seems to me like it does expect a value inside @"Anne" and not the name of a string, but may be I am wrong. Do you think it should work the way it is ?